# When I need some item, should I just use its "int id" instead?

Tags: c#, oop

My application has `InstrumentFactory` - the only place where I create `Instrument` instance. Each instrument instance contains several fields, such as `Ticker=MSFT` and `GateId=1` and also unique `Id =1`.

And now I realized that I almost never need `Instrument` instance. In 90% of cases I just need `Id`. For example now I have such method:

```
public InstrumentInfo GetInstrumentInfo(Instrument instrument)
{
    return instrumentInfos[instrument.Id];
}
```

We know that we should not pass in parameters more information than required. So this code probably should be refactored to:

```
public InstrumentInfo GetInstrumentInfo(int instrumentId)
{
    return instrumentInfos[instrumentId];
}
```

90% of my code can now be refactored to use `instrumentId` instead of `Instrument`.

Should I do that? Changing everywhere `Instrument` to `instrumentId` will make it as a hard requirement (each Instrument should have exactly one unique id). But what benefits will I have? In return of "hard requirements" I want to have some benefits for that... (speed, readability?) But I don't see them.

Comment: Or maybe GetInstrumentInfo should be a method on Instrument?

Comment: @Peri has a very good point. Or perhaps a property getter would be even better still.

Comment: @Peri disagree. I have a lot of information associated with Instrument, for example "orders of Instrument" in addition to "instrumentInfo". I need this information in different parts of my program. Putting everything into class instance will make it pretty "dirty" and unmanagable...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using ids everywhere instead of the object is wrong approach and it goes against the spirit of OOP.

There are two big advantages to using the object itself:

1. It's type-safe. You can't accidentally pass something like `Person` to the first version, but you can accidentally pass `person.Id` to the second.
2. It makes your code easy to modify. If, in the future, you decide that you need `long` ids, or some other way to identify a unique `Instrument`, you won't need to change the calling code.

And you should probably change your dictionary too, it should be something like `Dictionary<Instrument, InstrumentInfo>`, not `Dictionary<int, InstrumentInfo>`, like you have now. This way, you get both of the advantages there too. To make it work, you need to implement equality in `Instrument`, which means properly overriding `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` and ideally also implementing `IEquatable<Instrument>`.

Comment: i don't use dictionary. i use array for perfomance reason. so I access it by `int` index.

Comment: And are those performance reasons real? You should write clean code first and if it turns out it's too slow (as showed by profiling), then optimize it.

Comment: that's why I have id. I need a lot of maps "instrument to something". originally I was using a lot of Dictionaries. Having `id` I now can use just `arrays`. This is very convenient because application spents a lot of time accesing something by Instrument.

Comment: If you're sure the difference between array and dictionary is important for you, you could create a custom `IDictionary<Instrument, T>`, that internally uses an array.

Comment: what for? why not just use array? are arrays out of date? :)

Comment: to be sure anyway I don't understand why can't i make hard reference "instrumentId = instrument". It's like every person on the planet has id (like passport). why can't Instrument has id...

Comment: and instruments do have id. for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Securities_Identification_Number I just introduce my own int id which is valid only in the context of my program.

Comment: Because you're losing type-safety that way. And it's not good encapsulation, `Instrument` should care about its `Id`, for for other types, identity of `Instrument`s should be transparent.

Comment: Unless it's inherent to the nature of the data that there are very few gaps in the objects, then you should use dictionary rather than array for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

It's always better to work in terms of objects than primitive values like integers. If tomorrow your requirements happen to change and you need more than just the ID, it is easy to add those to the `Instrument` object instead of changing all your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
GetInstrumentInfo(int instrumentId);
```

This probably means that the client code has to have a:

```
GetInstrumentInfo(instrument.Id);
```

Don't let the users of your method worry about small details like that. Let them just pass the entire object and let your method do the work.

Don't see any major performance disadvantage. Whether you pass an Int or reference to the actual object.

Say you wanted to develop GetInstrumentInfo a bit more, its easier to have access to the entire object than just an Int.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to ask yourself is this:

"If I have two instruments with ID == 53, then does that mean they are definitely the same instrument, no matter what? Or is there a meaningful case where they could be different?"

Assuming the answer is "they are both the same. If any other property differs, that is either a bug or because one such object was obtained after another, and that will resolve itself soon enough (when whatever thread of processing is using the older instrument, stops using it)" then:

First, internally, just use whatever you find handier. You'll quite likely find that this is to go by the `int` all the time, though you get some type-safety from insisting that an `Instrument` is passed to the method. This is especially true if all `Instrument` construction happens from an `internal` or `private` constructor accessed via factory methods, and there is no way for a user of the code to create a bogus `Instrument` with an id that doesn't match anything in your system.

Define equality as such:

```
public class Instrument : IEquatable<Instrument>
{
  /* all the useful stuff you already have */
  public bool Equals(Instrument other)
  {
    return other != null && Id == other.Id;
  }
  public override bool Equals(object other)
  {
    return Equals(other as Instrument);
  }
  public override int GetHashCode()
  {
    return Id;
  }
}
```

Now, especially when we consider that the above is likely to be inlined most of the time, there is pretty much no implementation difference as to whether we use the ID or the object in terms of equality, and hence also in terms of using them as a key.

Now, you can define all of your public methods in any of the following means:

```
public InstrumentInfo GetInstrumentInfo(Instrument instrument)
{
    return instrumentInfos[instrument];
}
```

Or:

```
public InstrumentInfo GetInstrumentInfo(Instrument instrument)
{
    return instrumentInfos[instrument.Id];
}
```

Or:

```
public InstrumentInfo GetInstrumentInfo(Instrument instrument)
{
    return GetInstrumentInfo(instrument.Id);
}
private InstrumentInfo GetInstrumentInfo(int instrumentID)
{
    return instrumentInfos[instrumentID]
}
```

The performance impact will be the same, whichever you go for. The code presented to users will be type-safe and guarantee they don't pass in bogus values. The implementation picked can be simply that which you find more convenient for other reasons.

Since it won't cost you any more to use the instrument itself as a key internally, I'd still recommend you do that (the first of the three options above) as the type-safety and making it hard to pass in bogus values will then apply to your internal code too. If on the other hand you find that a set of calls keep just using the id anyway (if e.g. they are talking to a database layer to which only the ID means anything), then changing just those places becomes quick and easy for you, and hidden from the user.

You also give your users the ability to use your object as a key and to do quick equality comparisons, if it suits them to do so.

Comment: i have InstrumentFactory which guarantees that I always have only one Instrument instance for each Id. Also factory has several LookUp methods such as `public Instrument Lookup(int gateId, string ticker)`

Comment: If there's a guaranteed single instance globally, you don't even need that, since the default object equality and hashcode will work to take the `Instrument` as a key. (If the objects are mutable, threading can get tricky though).

Answer (score -1):

You could overload each function, one that takes an instrument and one that takes an id:

```
public InstrumentInfo GetInstrumentInfo(Instrument instrument)
{
    // call GetInstrumentInfo passing the id of the object
    return GetInstrumentInfo[instrument.Id];
}

public InstrumentInfo GetInstrumentInfo(int instrumentId)
{
    return instrumentInfos[instrumentId];
}
```

This will give you enough flexibility so that while you go through any place that calls `GetInstrumentInfo` to change it to pass id, the current code will still function.

As to whether or not you "should" is purely up to you.  You would have to weigh how much time it would take to change it versus the benefit of making the change in the code.